# Starting with Roku app development

Tags: roku, brightscript

I want to start learning Roku, can any one suggest me some sites and videos, doc, etc to start up.

please provide me some links

Answer (score 2):

You could start with the [Roku Developer Guide](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/RokuSDKv48/Developer+Guide), the [dev blog](http://blog.roku.com/developer/) and the [dev forum](http://forums.roku.com/viewforum.php?f=34).
And you might even want to download an existing sample [template](https://github.com/BrightcoveOS/Roku-Sample-App) to play around with - sometimes its easier to see an existing set up to determine what you need and can use.

Comment: Don't waist your time watching the roku videos on youtube.  They are full of bad information, and will be a complete waist of your time.  Dev Guide, Blogs, and any one else's code you can find.

Comment: [Roku Developer Guide](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/RokuSDKv48/Developer+Guide) is the best option.

Comment: Try this blog - https://www.codingalien.com/2017/01/02/brightscript-a-detailed-introduction/